# How to open Mathematica files from 1989 with ".bo" extension

Tags: files-and-directories

I have access to a collection of files from 1989, which appear to have been written for an early version of Mathematica. I was curious if anyone knows how I might open and read these files in contemporary versions Mathematica?
The files have the extension `.bo`

Comment: What happens when you simply open them from a current version of *Mathematica*?

Comment: Thank you, I tried it---it looks like it interpreted everything in the notebook as just text, as if I had opened any other text file

Comment: Now change the cell formats (e.g., `Input`, not `Text`).

Comment: It would help if you copy/pasted the first few dozen lines of the file to include in your question. We might be able to figure out what transformation of the file will make it useable.

Comment: Can you share an example of such a file? I am aware of `.ma` files but not `.bo`.